# Outline property on Fire Fox going around pseudo elements as :after & :before

Tags: html, css, browser, pseudo-element, outline

With Chrome the outline property is surrounding the main element but it is going between main element and :before pseudo element. On firefox the outline property is surrounding main element and :before as well. 
Is there any way to force the outline property to go between main element and :before/ : after pseudo elements?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: @JamesKorden Thanks for answer! I tried but unfortunately it didn't work.. :(